# Reflection Class.getDeclaredFields() is not retrieving anything

Tags: java, android, reflection

I've been using reflection in android development since last year without any problems. After updating my Android Studio 3.0 I noticed that everything related to Reflection, that was working until then, just stopped working. I am no longer having success when trying to retrieve fields from a class using the method `getDeclaredFields()`, the result is always an empty array.
After searching for almost a week, and trying a lot of different kind of stuff, I tried running an unit test with the code below, and it went well, but when I try to run the same code on an Activity, for example, I got no results, only the same old empty array.

```
Field[] fields = User.class.getDeclaredFields();
Log.d(HOME_ACITIVITY_TAG, "Count: " + fields.length);
for (Field field : fields)
     Log.d(HOME_ACITIVITY_TAG, "FieldName: " + field.getName());
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private int personId;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;
    private String facebookId;
    private boolean isActive;
    private Person profile;

    public User() {}
}
```

Is there anyone who knows what is happening? Most of my project are depending on this, I used Reflection for almost everything.

Best Regards

Comment: Please give us more information, such as how `User` defined.

Comment: Okay, just posted User.java. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running?

Answer (score 0):

I created a whole new project, named everything the same and moved all my dependencies there. It worked fine, but I still don't know what happened to my previous Project, so if anybody understood what was the problem I would be very glad to read about it, after all it could happen again, and I'm not comfortable with the idea of doing it over and over again.

Best Regards!

Comment: You must have been somehow running with an old version of `User.class`, but now that you've destroyed the evidence we can never know for sure.

Comment: I did not destroyed the evidence, it is still here. I just created a new project and copied the dependencies. I cleaned the build, used the "make project", a lot of times. Debugged on both Unit Test and Android Application, all the breakpoints matched. But I'm still up to try any other solution, for real.